# Error while trying to install mysql in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Ruby version** - ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

**Rails Version** - Rails 7.0.4

**Command** = `gem install mysql2`

## I have already install mysql community version and placed libmysql.dll in C:\Ruby31-x64\bin

**Error Details**

> Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW... Using msys2 packages:
> mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmariadbclient Building native extensions.
> This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/ext/mysql2
> ```
>
> C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
> checking for rb_absint_size()... yes checking for
> rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()...
> yes checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
> the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
> --with-opt-dir
> --without-opt-dir
> --with-opt-include
> --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
> --with-opt-lib
> --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
> --with-make-prog
> --without-make-prog
> --srcdir=.
> --curdir
> --ruby=C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
> --with-mysql-dir
> --without-mysql-dir
> --with-mysql-include
> --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
> --with-mysql-lib
> --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
> --with-mysql-config
> --without-mysql-config
> --with-mysqlclient-dir
> --without-mysqlclient-dir
> --with-mysqlclient-include
> --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
> --with-mysqlclient-lib
> --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
> --with-mysqlclientlib
> --without-mysqlclientlib C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `block in find_library': undefined method` split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>
> ```
> paths = paths.flat_map {|path| path.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)}
>                                    ^^^^^^
>     from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `each'
>     from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `flat_map'
>     from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `find_library'
>     from extconf.rb:103:in `<main>'
> ```
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
> which can be found here:
>
> C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.4/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4 for inspection.
> Results logged to
> C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.4/gem_make.out

Comment: Do check `C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.4/mkmf.log`

Answer (score 3):

This issue will resolve by installing

**sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev**

Comment: i'm seeing this issue while installing mysql2 gem v 0.5.4 on Mac Sonoma M2 chip. Any fix for this issue on mac? i've `brew install mysql-client` and that did not help